# Change default numeric associative array keys to "number" only without affecting array values

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter, associative-array

I have a form at http://97.74.37.64/ (visit it first) . It has only one textarea where visitor can fill upto 15000 number of mobile numbers. after submit it should be converted into an array (This one I have done).

Now, this array is like this below..

```
Array ( [0] => 9810000000 [1] => 9810000001 [2] => 9810000002 [3] => 9810000003 [4] => 9810000004 [5] => 9810000005 [6] => 9810000006 [7] => 9810000007
```

and so on..
Now, I want to change the key of the array to string "number" so it should be like

```
Array ( [number] => 9810000000 [number] => 9810000001 [number] => 9810000002 [number] => 9810000003 [number] => 9810000004 [number] => 9810000005 [number] => 9810000006 [number] => 9810000007
```

I want to do the above mentioned thing. Because I want to insert the mobile numbers into the MySQL table (one mobile number each row). This is the multiple insertion in MySQL table. My table name is `srchlist` with 2 fields `id`(its auto_increment & we don't need to mention or insert it) and `number` for which I am making array keys as number. So finally it should be inserted like below

```
id   |  number
---------------
1      9810000000

2      9810000001 

3      9810000002
```

and so on entire array values should be inserted..

Comment: You don't need to convert your array, can you show the INSERT your using to add the data which may help.

Comment: There can be nothing good here.

Comment: you cannot have the same key in the array

Comment: please visit the link http://www.dndsearch.in/ & http://ndnccheck.com/ndnc.php they do DND and non DND filter I need to make the application like those. I can not make the comparison until I use the inner join query and I can not use inner join query until I insert the data into the table srchlist.

Comment: why you want to change key to `number`?

Comment: @KrisRoofe : I think you are right.. I can not have the same value for each key.

Answer (score 0):

What about just organizing these values into an array of arrays? That way you can bulk insert them into your table or insert them as part of a loop if need be:

`array(
    array("number" => 1), array("number" => 2), array("number" => 3) 
)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

**Controller:**

```
// Array ( [0] => 9810000000 [1] => 9810000001 [2] => 9810000002 [3] => 9810000003 [4] => 9810000004 [5] => 9810000005 [6] => 9810000006 [7] => 9810000007)

    $number = array('9810000000','9810000001','9810000002','9810000003',,'9810000004','9810000005','9810000006','9810000007'); 
    foreach($number as $row)
    {
       $number1[]['number'] = $row;
    }

    $this->M_admin->numbers($number1); //call modal function
```

**Modal:**

```
function numbers($number)
{
    // insert into db as batch
    $this->db->insert_batch('numbers', $number);
}
```

Comment: how you will take those values to your project then?

Comment: By a textarea form in which person will insert phone numbers list.

Comment: so you want to get data from the textarea and insert right? And also the data in textarea will be separated by commas?